# How to get better Reputation when you can't Comment

Tags: support, comments, privileges

I often get the comment on my answers that "this should be a comment." They are right, it should be, but I can't because I need 50 rep to comment on questions.

I think it should be possible to comment without rep because many people out there are asking themselves questions to clarify other questions. For example...

> **User a** asks: How can I set a dyndns on my router?
>
> **User b** responds: Have you looked at the firewall settings on your router?

It's not really an answer, but it's good enough that it could lead him to find an answer himself. It's pedagogically better because now he knows the solution, **and** got the "I did it myself" feeling.

My problem now is that I can't help them help themselves the correct way, because I can only answer, not comment!

Comment: Stack Exchange values answers more than questions or comments, which is why comments don't give rep.  Further we want new users to focus on the core mission of the site - questions and answers - and ignore all else until they have done that part well.  If you focus on posting good answers and questions, the low barrier to posting comments will be easy to achieve.  If you want to focus on comments and not questions or answers, perhaps this isn't the best site for your expertise.

Comment: Imagine what would happen when anyone could comment. The amount of spam you'd get would be enormous! Also, answers are more easily moderated than comments (Community members can delete bad answers without the need of a diamond moderator to intervene). Comments require a moderator to clear them.

Comment: +1 for the use of "pedagogically", which 98% of the users here will need to google.

Comment: You will have better results if you use capital letters to begin sentences, and write *you* instead of *u*.  Other users can help fix your writing, but try your best to write well.

Comment: +1 for what Johnny said :D

Answer (score 10):

You get reputation by posting answers that *answer the question*, rather than answers that are comments.  (Or by asking quality questions, if that's your thing.)

If you can't provide an answer to the question, then don't post an answer; it's that simple.  There are some questions that you'll simply need to walk away from because you don't have the ability to answer them, or the tools to help the author (sometimes this is due to a lack of rep, sometimes for entirely different reasons).  This is a simple reality.  Find another question that you *can* participate in.

Answer (score 9):

It looks bad when you look at it that way yes.

But I assure you, not as bad as it would look if all new users would have the ability to comment. The amount of spam and non-constructive comment we would get would be non-manageable.

I recommend you find a question to which you can answer without further specifications from the OP or that you look at the currently posted comments to try and find the specifications you need and then answer the question. 1-2 good answers will get you to 50 rep easily.

This minimum rep assure that we get *more serious* users commenting. (There are exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

As new user you should focus on real answers and real questions.

You can also gain rep by suggesting useful, substantial edits. You get 2 rep for every approved edit.